# Sorting Data using Pandas Dataframes in Python

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, count, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I am trying to sort in a certain way.

The input:

```
CompanyName   count    assignee_name   CallType        recvd_dttm
Company3       4         Jill           Machine1       8/28/2015 13:46
Company3       4         Jill           Machine1       8/27/2015 13:26
Company3       4         Jack           Machine2       8/27/2015 11:46
Company3       4         Jill           Machine1       8/25/2015 9:56
Company2       3         Brad           Machine1       8/29/2015 12:43
Company2       3         Lee            Machine2       8/28/2015 13:44
Company2       3         Lee            Machine1       8/22/2015 19:45
Company1       2         Lee            Machine1       8/12/2015 14:47
Company1       2         Lee            Machine2       8/11/2015 13:44
Company0       1         Tracy          Machine2       8/31/2015 13:32
```

What I want:

```
Company3         Company2       Company1        Company0
4                3              2               1
Jill             Lee           Lee             Tracy
Machine1         Machine1       Machine1        Machine2
8/28/2015        8/29/2015      8/12/2015       8/31/2015
```

It should output the company name in order of who shows up in the dataframe the most. Then it should show the person who picked up the MOST calls. Then the information for CallType and recvd_dttm should be the most recent information.

I used this:

```
mode = (lambda ts: ts.value_counts(sort=True).index[0] 
                   if len(ts.value_counts(sort=True)) else None)
cols = df['CompanyName'].value_counts().index

df = df.groupby('CompanyName')[['count','assignee_name', 'CallType', 'receiveddate']].agg(mode).T.reindex(columns=cols)
```

And it outputs correctly by company name and count but chooses a random call for the other information, not the most recent call.

I was also looking into using something like `df.groupby(['CompanyName','count']).agg(lambda x:x.value_counts().index[0])`

but am getting `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 21285: ordinal not in range(128)` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# convert datetime string to pd.timestamp
df['recvd_dttm'] = pd.to_datetime(df['recvd_dttm'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')

def func(g):
    temp = g[g['recvd_dttm'] == g['recvd_dttm'].max()].iloc[0]
    temp['assignee_name'] = g['assignee_name'].value_counts().index[0]
    return temp.drop('CompanyName')

df.groupby('CompanyName').apply(func).sort(['count'], ascending=False).T

CompanyName               Company3             Company2             Company1             Company0
count                            4                    3                    2                    1
assignee_name                 Jill                  Lee                  Lee                Tracy
CallType                  Machine1             Machine1             Machine1             Machine2
recvd_dttm     2015-08-28 13:46:00  2015-08-29 12:43:00  2015-08-12 14:47:00  2015-08-31 13:32:00
```

Comment: Yes! This gets me one step closer. The next thing is to get the assignee_name to be the name that shows up the most for that CompanyName. Would you know how to get that?

Comment: Like in this case, for Company2 Lee would show up, not Brad because he appears more for Company2 calls.

Comment: @jenryb I've edited the post to address that issue. :-)

Comment: Hmm. This doesn't seem to work quite right. My code uses the dataframe later to pull certain information, and the format for your second answer is very different than the format that results from your first (There is other data in the dataframe that I've been ignoring for now that is getting in the way)

Comment: @jenryb just fixed it. Pls have a look. :)

Comment: Thanks for the fix :) looks like the dates are off now. I am only using the code in the EDIT section, should I also be using the df.sort from the first part?

Comment: @jenryb sorry for that confusion. I've edited the post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88842/discussion-between-jenryb-and-jianxun-li).

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
In [121]: most = df.groupby('CompanyName')['assignee_name'].transform(lambda x: x.value_counts().idxmax()))

In [122]: df = df[df['assignee_name'] == most]

In [123]: df = df.sort(['CompanyName', 'recvd_dttm'])

In [124]: df = df.groupby('CompanyName').last()

In [125]: df
Out[125]: 
             count assignee_name  CallType          recvd_dttm
CompanyName                                                   
Company0         1         Tracy  Machine2 2015-08-31 13:32:00
Company1         2           Lee  Machine1 2015-08-12 14:47:00
Company2         3           Lee  Machine2 2015-08-28 13:44:00
Company3         4          Jill  Machine1 2015-08-28 13:46:00
```

Comment: This is great, but not the format I wanted, which is very important for the rest of the code. I will look into formatting it the same.